# Trying to find general solution using method of characteristics of a quasi linear advection equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to find the general solution for the following PDE
$$ x {\partial\phi(x,y)\over\partial x} + c y {\partial\phi(x,y)\over\partial y} = - \phi(x,y)$$
where $c = \frac{(\alpha - 1)}{\alpha}$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$.

The characteritic equations are
$$
\frac{d x}{x} = \frac{d y}{cy} = \frac{d \phi}{-1 }.
$$
As per my understanding, We now want to find two functions $\Phi(x, y, \phi)$, $\Psi(x, y, \phi)$ ) such that $d \Phi = d \Psi = 0$. The general solution is then given by $F(\Phi, \Psi) = 0$ with $F$ an arbitrary function.
Using 
$$
\frac{d x}{-x} = d \phi \implies d(\phi + log (x)) = 0
$$
and 
$$
{dx\over dy} = {x\over c y} \implies  c y dx -  x  dy 
$$
we obtain
$$
\Phi =  \phi + log (x),
$$
but i am not sure how to pick $\Psi$ in this case it appears $x \approx y^c$.

Could i instead work with the ode
$$
\frac{d y}{cy} = \frac{d \phi}{-1 } \implies d(c \phi + \log (y)) = 0.
$$

The general solution is then given by 
$$
F(\phi + log (x), c \phi + \log (y)) = 0
$$
but since both terms depend on $\phi$ i am not sure if i can get an expression for $\phi$.

Is there a way to get an general solution expression for $\phi$ ? is there a way to pick a better $\Phi$ ?

Comment: no since $F$ is arbitrary

Comment: Is there a way to pick a different $\Phi$ ?

Comment: it doesn't matter your solution will be still implicit one

Comment: @daulomb its just that an explicit solution leads to more opportunities for further research.

Comment: I  notice that the equation is linear one. I think that you made a mistake while you were obtaining the general solution. The solution $\phi$ can be expressed in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completion of your solution: $$
\frac{d x}{-x} = d \phi \implies d(\phi + log (x)) = 0\Longrightarrow \phi + \log (x)=c_1 \qquad(1)
$$
and 
$$
{dx\over dy} = {x\over c y} \implies  c y dx -  x  dy =0\Rightarrow x-y^c=c_2\qquad (2)
$$
Thus the general solution can be written as $c_1=f(c_2)$, or equivalently 
$$\phi =-\log(x)+f(x-y^c),
$$
where $f$ is any differentiable function.

Comment: yeah i can see my error too now. thank you so much.

Comment: you are welcome